How to deal with irrelevant gotcha questions?
A question like this According to LDS, why doesn't omniscient God know about the existence of any other Gods?  is a nuanced question branching off of two other related question.
It's nitpicking at the LDS faith in a way that if an adherent were probing would be thesis material, but if a detractor asks appears as a "gotcha".  As a non-biased moderator, I would say that these questions are OK because they're simply probing futher.  As a biased Catholic, I would say that these questions are great because they're simply should be asked. But as a sympathetic person, I don't want to see religious sensibilities get hurt or people score points against another sect simply because that sect doesn't offer up a definitive answer about something specific.
So, what do we do about those questions?  There was, traditionally, a close reason for "too narrow" like "applies only to me"  and if only the person asking the question actually cares about the answer to the question do we want those questions on the site?

How shall the asker know if he alone is interested in the answer to any particular question?  How many other interested parties must sign on to legitimize a question?

@MikeBorden how do we know when someone asking is earnest or is willing to accept someone else's interpretation? Plenty of similar questions are closed to be duplicate, even as there is clearly an interest by people as the question is re-asked.

@depperm Intent can be tricky to discern.  None of the suggested duplicates are actually duplicates.  Thus far the answer to "Does this answer the question" has been  no.

@MikeBorden I believe they are, from an LDS perspective. You say no, but that could be because you don't accept it as an answer, doesn't mean it isn't a dup

@depperm If you had the gold [tag:lds] badge you could mod-hammer close as dupes whatever you wanted.  Geremia does that with Catholicism questions, but he's gotten into kerfluffles on a few of those.  I, personally, think the ones you cited were clearly intended to be probing deeper rather than simply re-asking. That's all the more I'm going to say about intent, it's not up to me to judge intent; but I can say I want people to have good intentions who participate here and I do not want those intentions to be to crap on LDS.

@PeterTurner the ones I cited weren't re-asking they were the original, the question in OP is the re-asking and I don't understand how it's different. Maybe I should've flagged it as needs details & clarity, but I felt the other questions answered it. When it remained opened, I attempted to re-answer, but I don't see any of the answers gaining traction-not as Truth but answers to the question. If the OP can't clearly define why the other answers don't answer, how is anyone expected to provide an answer to the question?

On this site, it has to be expected that one's own faith will be tried and tested. One's own understanding of what one perceives as being 'Christianity' will be sifted and searched.
It is one of the features that is exhilarating within Stack Exchange that one must, in an academic framework, and based on a factual foundation, prove one's own grasp of one's own position, one's own viewpoint.
Questions will be asked which, at the first, appear to attack my very faith, my very raison d'etre, and if that upsets me, then I have to question whether I should be here at all.
But it does not. For I am able to answer all that anyone can bring up in query of that which I believe.
And on those most rare times when I am at a loss for words, I will find someone else has answered and I can simply add my vote to their more competent effort.

On this particular question I have to say that it is a question that is begging to be asked.
It is a fundamental point about the very foundation of the ideology.
Not to ask it would be academically remiss. It begs to be asked. It must be asked.
And I still await a logical answer . . . . . .

Can you see no other interpretation of the given text? If you can't be open minded asking about other beliefs is kind of pointless

@depperm No, I cannot see any other 'interpretation'. It means exactly what it says. Scripture is not ambiguous so that anyone can make it mean anything they like. It means what it says.

Its a question of understanding the meaning of the text. From duplicate question answer Isaiah 47:8-10 on the city of Babylon...none else beside me...Seems to exclude any other city but in Zephaniah 2:15 on the city of Ninevah, it has the same phrase.

can't a father make a similar claim "Is there a different father [of my child] beside me? yea, there is no other; I know not any" and it not be about omniscience?

@depperm That makes no sense to me. The phrase is correct in both contexts. I cannot understand  what it is you are attempting to argue. And is that your whole response ?

I provided 2 comments.  The phrase is correct in both contexts but the Bible only has one interpretation because....I provided an answer that goes into more detail

also this is the very problem I'm talking about youI still await a logical answer says you are looking for a 'convince me' answer, which isn't the purpose of the site

Nigel, this is the problem with the ecumenical nature of this site.  There's an implicit assumption that if you can ask a question of Sect A, you can ask it of Sect B.  Well,  Sect B might have that question in its "blind spot", to use a driving analogy, and no amount of academic rigor will unearth an answer.

I don't see the question as a blind spot, beyond those who don't fully grasp LDS doctrine which is unique. Even when one doesn't accept LDS doctrine, if you can't accept LDS doctrine as being LDS doctrine, getting an LDS answer won't help. The only way it's a blind spot is if you are searching for an answer that answers in a non-LDS manner or a gotcha question

@depperm As Peter Turner states, an ideology may represent something as axiomatic (such as Einstein stating that the speed of light is constant) and then regard it as something not to be questioned or as something beyond questioning. 'Accepting' doctrine is not something I do on this site. I question everything from a logical and academic point of view. And I do expect everything to be available to question.

@NigelJ I'm not saying not to ask questions. If you ask if x+2=4 what is x, and then later if 2+x=4 what is x, that isn't a probing question, that is a duplicate. This point has been questioned, multiple times, in multiple ways and has answers. It isn't accepting doctrine so much as accepting another denominations perspective.

@depperm Asking 'How does a certain Body handle certain kinds of texts ?' is an entirely different question to 'Why does God state that he does not know of any other gods ?' Yes, it is within a common subject area but it is asking from an entirely different aspect. This is how good research is done : to approach from different angles, different viewpoints in order to determine the real condition of what is under analysis.

@NigelJ this question asks the same thing, this answer goes over LDS interpretation of the verse, this question also answers it, and this answer answers it. This new question adds nothing new to the question or points out what is not clear from any of the given answers. Research it

Asking the same question again and again is not good research, SE closes duplicates. You have to add something new to the question, and I'd argue this question has been answered from an LDS perspective at least 3 times on other questions. I'm not opposed to different angles/viewpoints, but I don't see how the question is different.

@depperm Then I am afraid we have to differ. As a Scientist, I query from every possible aspect before forming a conclusion.

@NigelJ so duplicates should be allowed to query every possible aspect? How do we on SE differentiate between duplicates or not? Is it opinion, perspective, close enough, or something else? Can you edit your answer to explain how each of the provided examples don't answer the question?

@depperm I am answering the Moderator's question. The examples you refer to are not part of that question. You should feel free to ask another question . . . . . . .

@NigelJ if you are making a general claim Scripture is not ambiguous I.e. that the Bible is sufficiently unambiguous that it cannot rationally be interpreted more than one way, then you are claiming that almost everyone who has ever read the Bible is irrational because they do not agree with you 100%. That's quite the claim.

@NigelJ hoping it could be addressed here, but here you go

No scripture is of any private interpretation. (Saith scripture itself.)

@NigelJ I do not follow your response. Since multiple interpretations of many passages do exist, are you proposing that all interpretations (save your own) are erroneous/irrational private interpretations?

@HoldToTheRod I refer you to my previous comment. No private interpretation is acceptable. The text plainly states something and does not invite private interpretations. This could not be more clear.

There was a relevant discussion in the Upper Room not long ago -- I'll cite 3 comments which can be found here, here, and here. The question that prompted the discussion was what is a stump the chump question?

here's a rule of thumb I've used when contemplating questions I might want to ask - if someone were to write an articulate response that addressed the question -- and I disagreed with the response -- would I still be willing to click it as the "accepted" answer? That's not a rule on the site, just my personal rule of thumb. If I'm not willing to accept an answer, no matter how well-constructed, there's a good chance I'm asking a stump-the-chump question.

&

That's a really good way of thinking about it! I was struggling with exactly how to define a stump the chump question. Focussing [sic] on your reaction to answers is probably pretty helpful.

&
(From a different part of the discussion):

I'm currently testing a hypothesis that...the site does not have a critical mass of non-trinitarians to vote to close bad/off-topic questions that misrepresent non-trinitarians (when a poor question is asked of trinitarians, the site users are able to close the question very quickly). Unfortunately, this means that poor questions can stay open as long as they make fun of the right people, and the only recourse is if a mod votes to close.

(for those keeping score at home, so far my hypothesis stacks up pretty well against the data).

As it relates to this question, I don't see any problem with the subject matter of the question itself, or its multiple related predecessors. Latter-day Saints are in fact well aware of these verses (surprise!). But if the question is not asked with real-intent (e.g. I actually want to know how the group in question understands X), it becomes but one more in a long line of questions on this site that play a useless game:

Step 1 - ask a gotcha question of a minority viewpoint

Step 2 - rely on weight of numbers to upvote answers which don't actually answer the question, but criticize the minority viewpoint

Step 3 - barrage anyone genuinely attempting to answer the question with comments until they have to move on with their lives and can't devote further time to the discussion. All the better if less-scrupulous users can be commissioned to assist in this and throw in some downvotes while they're at it [Remember that the downvote button on the Main site means "you're a heretic" =)]

Step 4 - whatever you do, don't ever accept an answer, no matter how clearly it explains the viewpoint that was asked about, if you don't agree with it. That might come across as an endorsement. [Remember that if you accept an answer from another religion on Stack Exchange it's definitely going to be the first thing that comes up on Judgement Day].

Intended result - a question criticizing a minority viewpoint is followed by upvoted answers that do not represent the viewpoint asked about [what was that 9th commandment again...?], and any responses which potentially do cast the minority viewpoint in a positive (or at least plausibly rational) light are safely hidden at the bottom of the page and thoroughly ratioed.


If this is the game we're going to play we should just be honest, drop the academic pretenses, and call ourselves an evangelizing site.
But if we want to live up to the purposes of the site described here, here, and here, we probably shouldn't play this game.

For the record I (and I hardly think I am alone) do upvote and even accept answers I strongly disagree with if they answer the question.  Often, however, answers simply raise more questions for clarification and these may come across as provocative.

@MikeBorden I hope that is the case, and I included the word if before the question is not asked with real intent to acknowledge this possibility. I don't think it's fair for me to ask how you voted on a given question, but since accepted answers are public knowledge, can you share an example of a non-trinitarian answer that you strongly disagree with but nonetheless selected as the accepted answer?

@MikeBorden for the record, "less scrupulous" was not a reference to you or your question. I looked this up a while back re a different user, who has asked dozens of questions of non-trinitarians, received many articulate responses, and never accepted a single one of them. This, to me, is not asking with real intent.

Here's one:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/94294/47250

@MikeBorden thanks!

And another:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/92797/47250

Step 2 is definitely not the policy of this site. Non-answers will be deleted. Of course the difficulty is that we can have genuine disagreements over whether something is a legitimate attempt at an answer. Likewise step 3 is not okay. Comment barrages need to stop. We may need to increase our giving out of suspensions if this is happening more and more.

@curiousdannii here is a recent example of a question on the site that attempts to execute all of the steps I've outlined above. The comment barrage here is particularly disappointing in how effectively it demonstrates the game I've described.  The mods' efforts to curtail the growing list of non-answers is certainly appreciated. It is a shame that some of those participating in this game are experienced users of the site.

Questions that build upon previous questions and answers (which may be built upon even previous questions and answers) are admittedly more work to answer and to moderate (kudos), especially as regarding potential duplicates.  They are also more difficult to ask responsibly.  We all need to count the cost.
This deep into things (at Meta) it is difficult to address all of the contributing information.  Many questions and answers have been asked, read, and incorporated.  Early on I made an edit in the OP in response to suggested duplicates:

A point of clarification: This question is not about God's declarations of singularity and how LDS interprets them. This question asks why omniscient God does not know of the other Gods that LDS claims exist.

There has been enough discussion thereafter to warrant not only robust commentary to the question and all of the answers but also this Meta question and a related Meta question.  It remains, apparently, for me to defend that the OP is not a duplicate so that it will not be closed.

If the OP can't clearly define why the other answers don't answer, how is anyone expected to provide an answer to the question?

I thought to try to insert a defense somewhere that would address everyone and could not find the appropriate place:  Individual responses proved ineffective.  I thought to massively edit the OP but could not see how without invalidating virtually every answer (frowned upon and uncool).  I thought, recently, to delete and re-ask but didn't want to disappear what is, really, robust commentary valuable to the question at hand.  So I have opted for this.
Having read all of the suggested duplicate questions and the proposed answers I maintain that the question "According to LDS, why doesn't omniscient God know of any other Gods?" is not a duplicate:  That it has not previously been asked and answered.
The answers to the various suggested duplicates appeal to two primary lines of reasoning and sources:  1) An appeal to Moses 1:35 and, 2) an appeal to Isaiah 47:8-10 and Zephaniah 2:15.
-The appeal to Moses 1:35 -
Moses 1:35 says:  "But only an account of this earth, and the inhabitants thereof, give I unto you." and the argument is that all statements such as "There is no God beside me", "I am the first and the last", "There is no other savior", etc., are confined within the context of this earth and the inhabitants thereof.  In other words, God is not even addressing the existence of other Gods beyond the confines of this world and us because they do not concern us or our salvation.
This would be an acceptable answer if it addressed the omniscience of God (which the question is specifically regarding) either by redefining omniscience (according to LDS) or demonstrating how the statement "Is there a God beside me? yea, there is no God; I know not any." is limited, in context, to this world only when He has, in the same passage, partly defined His omniscience as knowledge of the future of this world wherein, according to LDS, some of us will become Gods.  The LDS definition of God's omniscience, as near as I can determine from official sources, is that He know all things and I've seen no limitations expounded.
- The appeal to Isaiah 47:8-10 and Zephaniah 2:15 -
The statement of God in Isaiah 44:8, "Is there a God beside me? yea, there is no God; I know not any." is said to be similar to Isaiah 47:8-10 spoken by Babylon:

Therefore hear now this, thou that art given to pleasures, that dwellest carelessly, that sayest in thine heart, I am, and none else beside me; I shall not sit as a widow, neither shall I know the loss of children: But these two things shall come to thee in a moment in one day, the loss of children, and widowhood: they shall come upon thee in their perfection for the multitude of thy sorceries, and for the great abundance of thine enchantments. For thou hast trusted in thy wickedness: thou hast said, None seeth me. Thy wisdom and thy knowledge, it hath perverted thee; and thou hast said in thine heart, I am, and none else beside me.

and that this claim is also made by Ninevah in Zephaniah 2:15:

This is the rejoicing city that dwelt carelessly, that said in her heart, I am, and there is none beside me: how is she become a desolation, a place for beasts to lie down in! every one that passeth by her shall hiss, and wag his hand.

thus proving that this statement is not a statement of actual exclusivity.
The context of both passages, though, are clear that these statements, made by these cities, are careless and born of wickedness.  Careless because obviously there are other cities and wicked because in pride they have lifted themselves up beyond bounds.  These are statements of unbounded pride and are decried as such in the very same passages by the Lord Himself.
The declaration that this statement of God, "I know of no other God", is identical to the boasts of these cities is to suggest that God is also foolish and wicked in so saying.  It ignores the context.  It obfuscates.  It claims similarity but disregards the glaring dissimilarity.
In my view, without a redefinition of God's omniscience or a clear explanation of why God's omniscience does not apply to Isaiah 44:8, the question has not been answered.  If the answer is that LDS scripture simply trumps what the Bible says, I will accept such an answer clearly stated.
I will abide by the moderator's rule on this question.

Interested in your thoughts on whether this is a viable resolution? I appreciate your desire not to edit a question so severely as to render existing answers obsolete. I added an appendix to my post to drill down on the very specific element of the question that has not been asked before.

Up-voted and fully agree that editing is not required and that the questions stands as un-duplicated.

Still not 100% clear to me what you are asking. Are you asking a) how the Father, Son, and Holy Ghost are said to be 3 distinct beings but are referred to as One God, or b) how the exaltation of God's children does not contradict either Isaiah 44:8 or 2 Nephi 9:20? If you are asking "a", this is a duplicate.

If you can clarify what you are asking we're happy to write or point to an answer, but there was no reference to future theosis in the original question, so it's not surprising that it wasn't a focus in anyone's answer.

@HoldToTheRod God is omniscient (present and future) and says he doesn't know any other Gods.  LDS claims that there are and will be multiple Gods.  I'm asking for the LDS explanation of why the omniscient God doesn't know of them.

The meta your referenced would be a better place for this question, and you don't address all the duplicate questions/answers. Part of one answer (of 15) references Zeph. The Moses/scope applies as long as you aren't closing your eyes to LDS perspective, which if you are kind of defeats the purpose of asking LDS perspective

@MikeBorden so what are the other Gods Yahweh knows about (per LDS)? 1) other members of the Godhead (Father, Son, and Holy Ghost know about each other), 2) other Gods which may exist in other realms (but whom we know next to nothing about), 3) people who will be exalted in the future. Are you seeking for an answer that addresses all 3? I ask because #1 has been covered on the site many times and is only relevant to this latest question if one rejects LDS terminology (but then why ask for an LDS view). #2 is pretty thoroughly addressed by existing answers to your question.

If it's #3 that you're asking about (wasn't referenced in original question but is now), I can certainly add a couple paragraphs addressing it.

@HoldToTheRod Is there a reason to break these other Gods down into categories?  If the answer is that the statement, "I don't know of other Gods.", is understood by LDS to mean, " I do know of other Gods." then simply state that as an answer and I'll accept it.

@MikeBorden I asked because 2 of the 3 categories have been pretty thoroughly addressed and I'm trying to understand what you are looking for that has not already been provided. In Isaiah 44:8 Omniscient God indicates that He knows of no other Gods that meet the criteria given in 44:7 (because there are none). I can apply that to any category above.

@MikeBorden if the question is genuine I'm still willing to write/update an answer, but if the only answer you're interested in is a false one (e.g. that LDS don't believe Isaiah 44:8) then the question is pointless, as the viewpoint it requests has been excluded from consideration a priori.

@MikeBorden I went ahead and edited further to make a good faith effort to respond to what I think you are asking. If that's not what you're asking (and you're not asking a duplicate of what's been asked before) would you be willing to share why? I would like to conclude that this isn't a question like those I described here, but I am struggling to reach that conclusion.

@HoldToTheRod The edits are fine.  I'm not sure which of the three distinct Gods is speaking in Isaiah 44, according to LDS, but the question is, "Why doesn't that God know, at the very least, that the other separate and distinct Gods exist?".

@MikeBorden thanks. Each member of the Godhead does know about each other - this is addressed in Appendix 2 of my post. Note that you'll seldom hear a Latter-day Saint refer to the Godhead as 3 Gods, for the reasons discussed in my monotheism post. You'll typically hear the term 3 Beings instead.

@HoldToTheRod Doesn't Isaiah 44:24, 45:7, 45:12, and so many, many other verses (not to mention Genesis 1:1) extend the set/scope/sphere within which God knows no other Gods beyond simply this one people on this earth?  He consistently depicts Himself not only as Israel's maker and redeemer but as the One who has made "all things", including the stars in the heavens, light and darkness, etc.

@HoldToTheRod When God says "I know of no other God"  He is speaking as one of three "separate and distinct beings" who are each God (LDS phraseology, not mine) within the set/scope/sphere you are insisting upon, right?  “… These personages … are called God the first, the Creator; God the second, the Redeemer; and God the third, the Witness or Testator.". (official LDS sourcing).

@HoldToTheRod  Their unity in will and purpose does not seem to disintegrate their distinction as separate beings:  “[It is] the province of the Father to preside as the Chief or President, Jesus as the Mediator, and the Holy Ghost as the Testator or Witness.” (LDS sourcing).   While on earth Jesus said "I and the Father are one" and never said "There's just me.".  Currently He is seated at the right hand of God, not just Himself.  Why, in Isaiah, does He speak of being singularly alone as you say?

@MikeBorden re Doesn't Isaiah 44:24, 45:7, 45:12, and so many, many other verses - I shared my thoughts on this in my post. God does know of other Gods. In Isaiah 43-44 (and elsewhere) the Lord contrasts Himself with false gods who ostensibly compete with Him, and He shows that they cannot truly compete with Him. Isaiah 44:8 answers the questions asked in the preceding verses - there is no other God who can answer these questions affirmatively. Any divine being which may exist in a universe we know nil about is not competing with God, nor doing for Israel what Isaiah describes.

I don't see that the scope/sphere of discussion in Genesis 1 is the same as that of Isaiah 43-44.

Re 3 separate beings - of course their unity in purpose does not disintegrate their distinction as separate beings - that's kind of the point. Isaiah 43-44 has been used as a challenge to both of our views and we resolve that challenge in different ways. If I understand your view correctly, "One God" means to you multiple Persons but one Being. I believe "One God"  can refer to multiple Persons and multiple Beings, who are being contrasted with the scheming, competing deities of polytheism. The Father & the Son are one in a way Zeus & Hades are not.

Eg John 17:22 - Jesus wants those He is praying for to be one - but not one being. Ergo, it is possible to be one without being one being. If the focus of your question is not about a) Deities in other universes (the initial links suggested that's where you were going), but about b) how LDS understand the Oneness of the Godhead...I'm back to thinking this is a duplicate question using a different verse to repeat a question. Or, if c) you're asking LDS to explain their views by starting with the trinitarian understanding of One God...we understand the term differently, so the question is moot

@HoldToTheRod It seems that the limited immediate context is actually required more by Moses 1:35 than the context itself.  At least, that is what I have gleaned from this conversation.  The text allows for God's making of everything (v. 24) and the appointing of the ancient people (v. 2, 21) to all be proofs of His statements, "Besides me there is no God (v. 6)", "I know of no other God" (v.8), etc.. and to serve as the ultimate basis of the folly of people worshiping anything or anyone else.

@HoldToTheRod  I don't agree with the imposition of limits by Moses 1:35, in that it also imposes limitation to God's knowledge.  He who created everything that there is and who knows the end from the beginning must surely know of other Gods if they exist.  However, I am going to accept Mason Wheeler's answer as the simplest and best explanation of what is actually going on:  LDS allows "new revelation" to trump or change or inform  what has been written.  I suppose I should have just accepted that answer right away.

@MikeBorden we could also ask what is the scope of Isaiah 44:24? That's probably more far afield than is necessary to answer this specific question though. Vss. 2 & 21 specifically identify God's dealings with Jacob/Israel as the focus.

@MikeBorden thank you for clarifying that you are not asking Latter-day Saints to explain their beliefs, but rather, you are looking for statements from Latter-day Saints that can plausibly reinforce what you have already chosen to believe about them. This is helpful context. I think Mason gave an excellent, concise answer and I upvoted it long ago, but it doesn't say anything about trumping or changing prior revelations - it says that in the scope they cover they are completely accurate!

There are irrelevant questions, and there are gotcha questions, but it does not necessarily follow that a gotcha question is an irrelevant question.
For irrelevant questions, it first has to be ascertained, "Irrelevant to whom? The entire community, or just a section of the community?" If the latter, then those here who see the question as being irrelevant to themselves should simply leave the question alone and continue looking for a question that is relevant to them. If the former, then it should be shut down by the Mods.
For gotcha questions, it first has to be ascertained, "Who is trying to catch out whom?" Depending on the answer, it should be worked out whether the question seems designed to make chumps of people answering, or not. For example, questions aimed at people who believe the one true God of the Bible exists, and/or that he created everything, challenging them to prove this, either with scientific proof or philosophical reasoning. Such questions have been done to death on here so it's easy to close another such one down as a duplicate. Of course, atheists on here are not inclined to stop 'worrying' this theological 'bone', and keep asking further questions. However, there can sometimes be a genuine question from a person who wants to know how best to answer an atheist on a particular point. Such a question should be allowed, even if there are linked answers going back many years, if only for answers to provide those links.
As for the example given here - the OP shows existing knowledge of LDS beliefs and literature, and wants LDS people to explain what seems like a tricky dilemma to him. It has to do with sorting out who the God that LDS people worship is, for he is not the only God in LDS theology, according to LDS doctrine. Of course, to LDS people, this might well seem like an irrelevant gotcha question, but if they have an answer (that satisfies them), all they have to do is state it, and give links to their literature. Or, if it strikes them as a duplicate, give links to previous questions where they reckon LDS people gave good answers to just that point. There are plenty LDS people on here to close the question down, if they have proper reasons so to do.
On the other hand, if the question exposes an area of LDS belief that they would prefer be kept away from public gaze, that is quite different. Perhaps they know that in order for the public to understand this theological point, they would first need to be initiated into deeper LDS theology that not even all of their own members are aware of. If so, a reasonable answer would be to just state that. I'm not saying that is the case - I'm just giving an example of how the question in question could be calmly dealt with by LDS people.
I have not answered that question as it is not relevant to me, but I am keenly interested in reading all the answers. I might learn something important, for the question raises an important topic. For sure, it is not an irrelevant question, either to LDS people, or to others on this site. There's nothing nit-picking about it, for it deals with a fundamentally important issue about the God we worship. And by "we", I include all other believers as well as LDS ones. For if it turns out that this LDS doctrine is correct, then all other believers are seriously wrong. And we ought to know about that, never mind who gets hot or bothered in the process.
So, my answer to the question is, first determine whether the question is irrelevant to the whole community. If so, shut it down. Second, then determine whether the question is purely out to make fools of those believing the matter under question. If so, shut it down. The second point is the most difficult to determine as motives are rarely admitted to by OPs and answerers, but if there's an opportunity for answerers to give a reasonable explanation, then that opportunity must remain open for them. On the other hand, if those who could answer (even with, "We don't really know") try to shut the question down because it makes them very uncomfortable, their motives are suspect. But who can ascertain motives not admitted to?

OP shows existing knowledge of LDS beliefs I disagree with, they think they do, but based on comments they have added their bias. who the God that LDS people worship is has been a question and has answers (this is from someone who knows LDS beliefs). all they have to do is state it we did by flagging it as dup. There are plenty LDS people on here I don't think there are 5 active LDS users, 3-4 come to mind. prefer be kept away from public gaze- nope clear duplicate. even all of their own members are aware of-there is so much information available to reference.

irrelevant question not the claim made. nothing nit-picking about it except that exact verse has been reference in multiple other answers, and the answer still isn't 'learned'. LDS doctrine is correct, then all other believers are seriously wrong we shouldn't/aren't here for the truth, its truth of specific denominations. Neither of the 2 last claims are what are being made, how do you handle a question that has a duplicate answer but OP doesn't want to accept that as answer?

I mean objectively irrelevant to the teachings of the particular sect - not subjectively irrelevant to users of the site (that's way too hard to judge).  Like, a question where no amount of probing would grant the OP any more insight into the teachings of that church.  There at least is some rationale for closing those kinds of questions.  IMO, with Catholicism, everything is on the table, but there's no reason to suppose that other groups can't have blind spots that have to be ignored if for no other reason than to guard their dignity.

@PeterTurner I really dislike this being portrayed as a blind spot. This question has been answered multiple times, in multiple ways, and by multiple people. If you close your eyes it doesn't make it a blind spot, it just means one refuses to see another perspective. If you put on rose tinted glasses and ask why is everything pink, that isn't a probing question, that is you laying your bias into the question.

If I claim my understanding of belief X (trinity) is correct and I ignore other answers that address the point, to re-ask a question, that isn't a blind spot I've found in a belief/denomination that is showing my bias and not reading other questions/answers.

@depperm well Mason's answer approximates the Catholic position on a number of these things.  Atheists would probably see that as a "blind spot" too when I just see "it's a mystery" and go with it.  However, I don't see how something fundamental, as "how many gods (or Gods) are there" is anything but a big hole in the LDS theology. I'm happy to admit it's a hole and say, we can't ask any more questions about it because they're all approximately the same question.  Are you saying that it should make sense and people who don't understand are missing something or that it doesn't matter?

@PeterTurner that is a different question, and one that probably doesn't have an answer in the same manner (I'd say its a mystery) we don't know how many humans there have been or what is heaven like. I'm saying the wording of the question has been asked before (the initial dup flag) and other answers reference the verse in question. The other answers should make sense and if you don't understand you are missing something. I can say the same thing about my understanding of the trinity. I've had trinity explained but I don't see how it makes sense, I must be missing something.

That said, I can't just open more and more questions as they would be flagged as dup. Do I now understand doctrine of trinity, no, are there answers, yes. Opening more questions to 'convince me' aren't necessarily beneficial. I'm not saying the question doesn't matter, that has never been my claim, it has been how is this any different from previous questions/answers. Please articulate so it can be answered in a way that is understandable-as this hasn't been done I assume its duplicate and they didn't read/understand previous questions

I opened my own question to try to understand other's perspective on this verse and the comments seem to indicate gods in the OT is referring to judges. If that is the case would this even apply to the LDS any differently?

I don't think this is a too narrow question or even applies just to me question. It is a duplicate.
The question is a decent one, but it has been asked and answered previously by multiple people. Just because you don't like an answer doesn't make it less of an answer. If I don't believe the doctrine of the trinity, do I get to keep asking the same question when I'm not convinced (no, because it has been asked and answered, even if I don't accept/believe the answer (logical/biblical/etc))?
On the point of probing further, how much probing is too much? We do mark similar questions as duplicates, and I can't see a distinction between the given question and the earlier two. If you look at the top answers for all of them they basically say the same thing. The oft quoted we can't handle the truth post comes to mind. I find it unlikely that convince me or refute this type questions benefit anyone.
US Judicial system has an objection asked-and-answered

is the objection available to an attorney when an opposing counsel asks a witness a question that has already been asked and received a proper answer.

Not liking the answer doesn't mean we should allow asking the same question.
I'm not against probing/interesting questions when the asker is actually seeking an answer (just to know how a specific denomination addresses it, not to convince the answerer). I bring this up as the OP doesn't seem to want to accept any given answers. Some of the comments:

Whether or not God is omniscient, as He claims to be, has no bearing on salvation? (the question does not mention salvation)
A difficulty with this interpretation is that the qualifier you suggest, "capable of providing you salvation" doesn't appear in the text. (nor does it appear in the question)
By a plain reading of the Bible omniscient God knows of no other Gods because there aren't any (there are questions/answers about trinity vs no trinity (and questions about LDS belief in other gods) with biblical basis. There obviously is not a clear reading as there is disagreement over meaning in Isaiah)

To the point of "I don't want to see religious sensibilities get hurt or people score points against another sect simply because that sect doesn't offer up a definitive answer about something specific." I don't think applies. I don't care about the points, I care more about providing quality answers to topics I have knowledge or interest in. It is frustrating seeing irrelevant, incorrect, and/or misleading answers to questions that interest me. It is equally frustrating having to explain the same thing to the same people, especially when the response is generally negative (I see this as someone in need of help (question), people offer help (answers)/there are already systems in place to help(duplicate answer), and the whole time people trying to help are being insulted). I believe I've answered most LDS questions that come up, unless I see an adequate answer already, I'm not afraid/hurt by questions. I'm trying to figure out how/why the question isn't a duplicate, and so far no one has provided an answer on why the other questions don't already answer it. Not liking an answer isn't a valid reason to ask again and again. This is a Christianity site where different people have different beliefs. You don't have to accept the answers as Truth but at least as truth to the denomination in question.

If an answerer introduces a topic (like salvation) which is not a part of the question or the referent text, shouldn't OP be allowed to investigate it's relevance as regards the question.

If the question is a duplicate and has already been answered elsewhere, please copy that answer to Mike's question (or copy it to here) so that we can all see the answer. (Which, as yet, we have not been given.)

@MikeBorden shouldn't you accept the provided interpretation even when it doesn't align to your beliefs-as the question is how LDS not Mike Borden or any other Christian address the question. Both instances of salvation in answer were the other gods have no bearing, which is why there is no God but God.

@NigelJ both questions are linked in the comments of the question this post is about

@depperm 'linked in the comments of the question this post is about' . . . .. .   I'm sorry I cannot find that. Can you please link to it ?

@NigelJ https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54772/how-do-mormons-interpret-isaiah-4310 and https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24058/how-does-the-lds-church-handle-verses-that-imply-there-is-no-one-like-god and maybe https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/81408/lds-church-view-of-hebrews-613-and-isaiah-4310

also this answer: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/34407/22319

Interested in your thoughts on whether this is a viable resolution.

I amended the question to ask about a contradiction between 2 Nephi 9:20 (God knows all things) and Isaiah 44:8 - as near as I can tell, this has not been asked before, and I think it preserves the essence of the question.
If the question is about how members of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints understand Deity or interpret passages about One God, this is a duplicate many times over. If it's a question about 2 specific allegedly contradictory passages, that's probably fair game and probably isn't a duplicate.
In the interest of full disclosure, in amending the question I also took the liberty of removing references to things Mason Wheeler and I have written as "official" teachings of the church. My post in fact included an explicit disclaimer that it is not an official teaching of the church =).
If a question is asked because one is genuinely seeking an answer, it's not an irrelevant gotcha question (the adherents in question might actually appreciate the opportunity to address a common misconception or criticism). If a question is asked with the intent to:

Reject all answers a priori OR
Start an argument in the comments OR
Demand a "convince me" or "convert me" response OR
Showcase that X group has no answer

Save it for evangelizing. It is not a constructive question for this site and should be closed. Intent may be difficult to ascertain up front, but it often becomes more obvious after the fact.

both works (doesn't hurt/take away) and it doesn't (doesn't change much). The doctrine of omniscience isn't limited to BoM (plenty of non-bible sources that LDS believe teach omniscience). I've seen, +1, your answer, but it 1) has a giant flowchart that shouldn't be necessary/doesn't answer the question (does gotcha part) and 2) doesn't differ too much from other answers for the answers there or elsewhere. I also provided an answer that doesn't differ too much, but I thought made but another way OP might understand (yours does go into greater detail).
